# ShowHide multiple li > blockquote #Quote

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the it so if you click the Quote it hides itself and shows the full review.

This current code  only works on the first list item. I can't seem to get it. It's probably something obvious, I just don't know jquery .

http://jsfiddle.net/TacoFiesta/L3a70h38/2/

```
<li><blockquote>
        <q id="Quote"><?php echo $rv['Quote'] ?></q>
        <q id="Review"><?php echo $rv['Review'] ?></q>
        <img src="images/reviews/<?php echo $rv['Image'] ?>">
        <cite>
        - <?php echo $rv['Name']; ?>
        - <?php echo $rv['Location']; ?>
        - <?php echo $rv['reviewDate']; ?>
        - <?php echo $rv['Site']; ?>
        </cite>
</blockquote></li>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Review").click(function(){
    $("#Quote").show();
    $("#Review").hide();
  });
  $("#Quote").click(function(){
    $("#Review").show();
    $("#Quote").hide();
  });
});
```

Thank you

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. You probably want to use classes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like j08691 (edit: and KoenW) said, you have to use classes instead, since IDs should be unique... you *could* find a way to get around that (find the parent element, and search within it for that ID), but that would defeat the purpose of having classes vs. IDs.

Try something like this instead:
http://jsfiddle.net/q7rypnxp/1/

(After changing the IDs to classes in HTML):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".Review").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".Quote").show();
    $(this).hide();
  });
  $(".Quote").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".Review").show();
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of an `id` attribute is unique to the page. You need to use classes (or different unique ids) in order for this to work.

Here is a forked jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/KoenW/n1fxhkkk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Change your `id="Quote"` to `class="Quote"`.  Do the same for `id="Review`"

Then change you jquery code to the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".Review").click(function(){
    $(this).prev(".Quote").show();
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $(".Quote").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".Review").show();
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Funny.. (id/class) Ya, I should have caught that. Thanks.